# How can I pop from a queue, process it, push to another queue, and it's thread-safe?

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, queue

It's a C++ program. There are 2 child thread and 2 queue.What I want to do is,

- Push something to the queue 1 in the main thread.
- The child thread 1 pop from the queue 1 and process it, then push it to the queue 2.
- The child thread 2 pop from the queue 2 and process, then output the answer.

How can I make it thread-safe? I think about two ways,

- Use a thread-safe queue. But does it means that I shouldn't use the queue of STL?
- Write thread lock. But how can I write 2 locks in one thread and lock the different part?
  It really puzzles me. Need help!!!! Any suggestion would be appreciated a lot!

Comment: See [`std::mutex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already said it. Lock the write and read access to every queue with a mutex. Queue 1 and 2 gets a mutex. It would be easy if you write your own push and pop function for the queues. Inside this function you could use std queues or else.

Comment: OK, I will try to write my Queue. I was just hesitate. I don't know what I think is right or not.  Thinks for your help!!! :)

Comment: You don't need to create your own queue.  Simply either use a muted to protect it, or use another thread safe queue such as from boost lockfree or Intel tbb

Comment: yeah, get it. Helps a lot !